# Замена иконки android

Tags: android

не могу понять как поменять круглую иконку в андроид, ставлю атрибут `android:roundIcon="@drawable/icon_round"` но он все равно пихает на рабочий стол телефона квадратную `icon` в круглой обводке, везде к слову `ic_launcher` и `ic_launcher_round` поменял на нужные мне иконки с соответсвующими названиями, но в `drawable` так же есть эти иконки с другими названиями, указанными в манифесте

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="SplitFit"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/icon_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: вы хотите полностью заменить иконку приложения, или только круглую?

Comment: только круглую, квадратная уже стоит из @drawable/icon

Comment: а вы поменяли квадратную только для одного разрешения?

Comment: честно говоря не знаю, можно по подробнее?

Answer (score 2):

Как вы уже поняли у приложения используются ресурсы которые отвечают за его иконку в лаунчере. Эта иконка может быть как квадратной так и круглой, но эти две формы иконки есть всегда. На данный момент есть огромнейшее количество устройств с самыми разными размерами экранов, и соответственно разрешений тоже есть немало.

Для того чтобы приложение приняло ту картинку которая вам нужна, и дальше ее отображало в лаунчере, независимо от того круглая или квадратная. У себя в проекте я использовал [этот](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html) ресурс. Здесь вы найдете самые разнообразные инструменты, не только для настройки и создания ярлыка, но и например для создания иконок внутри приложения. Все довольно просто, для начала у вас должна быть картинка, которую вы хотите поставить вместо дефолтной. Дальше вы переходите по ссылке и следуете в [эту](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=clipart&foreground.clipart=android&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0.25&foreColor=rgba(96%2C%20125%2C%20139%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(68%2C%20138%2C%20255)&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&effects=none&name=ic_launcher) часть сервиса. Именно здесь вам нужно будет выгрузить вашу картинку на сервис, где дальше вам будет сгенерировано иконку приложения, в двух формах и во всех доступных на данный момент разрешениях.

Дальше вам нужно как-то поменять стандартную иконку, на ту что вы сделаете в сервисе. Для этого я например, использую проводник, там в папке проекта вы находите папки с названием `mipmap-разрешение`, именно в этих папках и хранится ваш ярлык. С вышеприведенного сайта вы сможете загрузить архив где будут все ярлыки отсортированные в нужные папки с нужным разрешением, и вам нужно будет только переместить все в соответствующую папку в проекте. Если все сделать правильно, то в итоге у вас будет свой ярлык у приложения. Надеюсь я помог в решении вашего вопроса, если будут какие-то сложности или что-то будет не понятно, то не стесняйтесь и спрашивайте, помогу чем смогу. Удачи:)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый