# Иконка приложения меняется только после смены идентификатора

Tags: android, icon

Есть проект на Android Studio в котором я тестирую приложение на своем телефоне. При попытке смены иконки ничего не происходит даже если очистить кэш, переустановить приложение или перезагрузить телефон. Смена иконки происходит лишь только в том случае если я в конфиге меняю widget id на новый. Подскажите с чем это связано и как решить?

Comment: В чем заключается "попытка смены иконки"?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/887366/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-android/887381#887381

Comment: Launcher смените в телефоне.